# How to implement scope highlighting like BlueJ in tkinter textbox?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I make a scope highlight feature in tkinter textbox like in Bluej?

It should look like this
[image]

The following is the code upto which I could do but couldn't figure out how to make it look like the above picture.

```
import tkinter as tk
#some random color (will replace with required colors later)
colorls = ['#A7E08E', '#F2EF94', '#FFBAF1']
def on_change(event):
    textblock =  text.get('1.0', tk.END)
    leftbrace_coor = []
    rightbrace_coor = []
    row = 1
    char = 0
    r, co = text.index( 'insert' ).split( '.' )

    for i in range(0, len(textblock)):
        char+=1

        if repr(textblock[i]) == repr('\n'):
            row +=1
            char = 0

        if textblock[i] == '{':
            leftbrace_coor.append((row, char))
        if textblock[i] == '}':
            rightbrace_coor.append((row, char))


    if len(leftbrace_coor) == len(rightbrace_coor):
        currentcolor = 0
        for i in range(0, len(leftbrace_coor)):
            currentcolor=(currentcolor+1)%3

            l = leftbrace_coor[i]
            r = rightbrace_coor[-i-1]
            text.tag_add(f"{l[0]}", f"{l[0]}.{l[1]-1}",f"{r[0]}.{r[1]}")
            text.tag_configure(f"{l[0]}", background=colorls[currentcolor], foreground="black")


win=tk.Tk()
win.geometry("700x350")

text=tk.Text(win, width=80, height=15, font=('Calibri 12'))

text.insert(tk.INSERT, "{\n    {\n        {\n        }        \n     }\n}\n")
text.pack()


text.event_add( '<<REACT>>', *('<Motion>','<ButtonRelease>', '<KeyPress>', '<KeyRelease>' ) )
text.bind( '<<REACT>>', on_change )

win.mainloop()
```

My one looks like this-
[image]

I am a beginner so please suggest a better way (if any) to implement the question.

Comment: It will take a lot of code but basically, you will need to parse the text yourself and add the highlighting yourself. Do you know how `tk.Text` tags work - you will need them a lot?

Comment: There is lots of information and plenty of examples of adding highlighting to a span of characters in a text widget. It's not clear what part of the problem  you need help with. Please add a [mcve] that shows what you've tried and illustrates the problem you're having.

Comment: What you are suggesting is extremely difficult. Syntax highlighting in `tkinter`.

Comment: this is syntax/programming language specific, and need to be handled as per programming language syntaxes. You can do this as other previously pointed, but it's hard because of that reason (mostly). Now, I did find something made using tkinter that does something similar, although it's only done whenever debugging is involved: [Thonny](https://thonny.org/). You can look into it's codebase if you're curious.